# numeric и всё о нём в Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

1. Параметры этого типа данных указываются в круглых скобках после имени типа: `numeric(точность, масштаб)`. Например, `numeric(6, 2)`.
   То есть мы ставим допустим 6, 2. Получается 9999,99 максимальная точность и масштаб если мы задаем numeric (6,2), правильно? А если мы не знаем сколько приблизительно будет точность и масштаб. Как вы в работе работали с эти типом numeric? Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с этим типов, совсем не понимаю :(
2. чем отличается numeric от того же real, double?

Answer (score 1):

> А если мы не знаем сколько приблизительно будет точность и масштаб.

Как и для `varchar` числа в скобках - дополнительное ограничение типа данных, но не обязательный элемент синтаксиса.

```
create table numtest (
  num numeric
);
```

Является [полностью допустимой записью](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) и ограничена только особенностью реализации, т.е. весьма далеко

> up to 131072 digits before the decimal point; up to 16383 digits after the decimal point

К слову, возможность хранить в `numeric` без указания точности дробные числа - отступление от стандарта `SQL`. По стандарту такой numeric должен хранить только целочисленные значения.

Тем не менее обычно диапазон указывают исходя из достаточного для предметной области смысла. Например, для баланса денег на счету сложно предположить необходимость в 100 знаках до запятой.

---

> чем отличается numeric от того же real, double?

`real` и `double` - это числа с плавающей запятой распространённого стандарта IEEE Standard 754. Что про них надо знать - это числа фиксированной длины в байтах, но приблизительные. Нужны для областей, где важно различать порядок величин и значение имеют только показатель степени и некоторое число значащих цифр, а малыми различиями можно пренебречь в угоду экономии памяти и CPU. Посчитав `(0.1+0.7)*10` вы можете получить `7.99999(9)`

`numeric` же штука большая и не такая простая, специально учитывающая точные вычисления.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала ответ на второй вопрос: они отличаются точностью. У numeric они фиксирована.
Если взять numeric(18,4) со значением 1,0001 и умножить на 10000 вы точно получите 10001,0000. В случае с плавающей точкой результат может отличаться, и быть, например, 10000,999999763 или 10001,00000013

Если вы даже приблизительно не знаете какая точность вам нужна, значит вы или плохо исследовали предметную область или вам нужны числа с плавающей точкой.

PS для хранения денег нужна фиксированная точность.

Comment: Так денег может быть много и может не хватить диапазона?

Comment: Я не допонимаю numeric

Comment: numeric - это примерно так, как учили считать в школе - считаем нацело, а потом сдвигаем запятую на нужное количество разрядов. С тем лишь различием, что если вылезли за диапазон справа от запятой, то округляем, а если слева - ошибка переполнения.

Comment: Самая большая известная мне сумма денег - гос.долг США, приблизительно 20 триллионов $, т.е. влезет в numeric(15,2). Я обычно использую numeric(18,2) - эта точность доступна во всех РСУБД